# Bash script that runs parallel threads slows down substantially over several hours

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, performance, for

I have a script I came up that simply executes another process into the background that attempts to control the max number of processes running (300 in this case).

It initially executes scripts at approx. 1-2 milliseconds, but after several hours of running it will eventually slow down in a linear slope to 200ms - 350ms execs.  I'm using an array to maintain PID# but also unsetting the key to reduce the table size, but I have a feeling that, that's the culprit.

```
#!/bin/bash

threads=()
threadcounter=0

crd=0;

while true; 
do
        threadcounter=${#threads[@]}
        crdcounter=${#crds[@]}

        if [ "$threadcounter" -lt 300 ]
        then
                s1=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
                pidf=$(/opt/remi/php/root/usr/bin/php cli.php initformula $crd >> /tmp/logger) &
                pidfid=$!
                s2=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
                echo "Init " $crd $(expr $s2 - $s1 ) "ms"
                threads[$pidfid]+=$pidfid
        else
            for pid in "${!threads[@]}"; do 
                if [ ! -d "/proc/${pid}" ]
                then
                    unset threads[$pid]
                fi
            done;
        fi;

        if [ "$crd" -gt 9999999 ]
        then
            echo "completed all";
            exit;
        fi;

        crd=$(expr $crd + 1)
done;
```

Comment: If you have a new enough GNU xargs, you should probably use it with `--max-procs` or GNU `parallel` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The original code.

When you start off you just start 300 copies of `cli.php`. This takes about 1200 processes because you want to measure the time taken to launch.

You then loop the variable `crd` from 300 to 9999999.

- If the shell thinks there are spare slots in the `threads` array it will start a new `cli.php` using the 4 processes.
- Otherwise you loop over approximately 300 processes getting the
  kernel to populate the `/proc` virtual filesystem, and testing if a
  directory exists. Any missing directories will cause entries to be
  deleted from the `threads` array.

You have a unused array called `crds`.

Because after the initial 300, each loop of the crd variable will create 1 new copy of `cli.php` if there are free slots in the process table, but can remove up to 300 if the table is full, at the end of the run we only knew that between 300 and about 9,967,000 `cli.php` processes have been started, with the number being determined by how fast your machine is, how long `cli.php` takes to execute and the load on the machine. 6 orders of magnatude is a lot to have to optimize over!

A rule of thumb is that on a modern machine starting 1 process takes 1ms on one core, so you are not doing badly at your initial launch rate. I would expect a significant kink in the launch rate once you run out of free cores to launch new processes.

#### Improvements

One way to speed this up would be to use `! kill -0 $pid` rather than `[ ! -d "/proc/${pid}" ]` - `kill -0` doesn't kill anything but gives an error return if the process doesn't exist. `kill` is a shell builtin (as is `[`) but the amount of work the kernel has to do is smaller. This will be most effective if most of time there are no free slots in the `threads` array.

A second improvement would replace the call to the external program `expr` with using the builtin `$(( ... ))` arithmetic, so reducing the overhead of launching a copy of `cli.php`. This is most effective if most of the time there are free slots in the `labels` array.

To do much more analysis we need to know the approximate time that `cli.php` takes to run, and how many runs there are.

As the `BUGS` section in the bash manual says `It's too big and too slow.` so it is certainly possible that there is scope for improving the array implementation in bash.

## Alternative Implementations

### make

In the comments it is suggested to use `xargs` or `parallel`. I frequently prefer using `make`. The first thing to determine how many copies of `cli.php` are wanted. Then a simple `Makefile` such as

```
%:
\t/opt/remi/php/root/usr/bin/php cli.php initformula $@
```

where \t is a tab character. (This simple version assumes you don't have any files with numeric names in the 0 to 9999999 range). Then invoke make as

```
make -O -j 300 $(seq 0 9999999) > /tmp/logger
```

if you want the full 10,000,000 cli.php invocations. Reasons why I prefer `make` to `xargs` include not needing to take excessive steps to abort the processing if cli.php returns errors.

### xargs

For an `xargs` solution try

```
seq 0 9999999 | xargs -n 1 -P 300 /opt/remi/php/root/usr/bin/php cli.php initformula > /tmp/logger
```

which is simpler.

### Bash

However a Bash solution which uses `wait -nf` and doesn't worry about tracking the PIDs at all might be more to the taste of the OP. It starts the initial 300 processes, then as it detects one of them finishing it will launch another. Once the 10,000,000th has been started it does a final wait to let all the jobs finish. Not exactly the same algorithm but very close.

```
#!/bin/bash
for(crd=0;crd<300;crd++); do
    /opt/remi/php/root/usr/bin/php cli.php initformula $crd & 
done > /tmp/logger
for(;crd<=9999999;crd++); do
    wait -fn
    /opt/remi/php/root/usr/bin/php cli.php initformula $crd &
done >> /tmp/logger
wait
```